# Configured/Initialized library in webpack globally

Tags: webpack

I want to get `web3` exposed as a global variable, via webpack.

Normally I would have to do this somewhere at the top of my app:

```
import truffle from '../truffle.js'
const rpcHost = 'http://'+truffle.rpc.host+':'+truffle.rpc.port

var web3 = new Web3()
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider(rpcHost))
```

And then pass the `web3` to every component in my app.
But I rather have this done in webpack once.

I've tried this in `webpack.config.js`:

```
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: "web3", loader: "expose?web3"}
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      web3: "web3"
    })
  ]
```

(With the former code included at the top)

But this is not exposing it the right way, i get a `function` back instead of an `object`, which it should be.

Comment: I think this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38278862/overriding-a-method-on-a-global-module-in-webpack/38295490#38295490) will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just making a file with the `web3` stuff in it, and exporting it. And just importing it in each module.

I would still like to know the `webpack` solution though.