# overriding a method on a global module in webpack

Tags: javascript, requirejs, webpack

I have something like this in my webpack config:

```
plugins:[
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ THREE: 'three' }),
  ...
```

which makes THREE available globally (or at least wherever its used?)

I would like to override a method from this library, for example in the entry point:

```
THREE.Something = mySomething;
```

I'm not succeding, how is this done?

Alternatively i tried something like.

```
require(expose?THREE!./myCustomThree.js);
```

But that didnt work either, i only got it in the scope where i made the require call. I was able to override the method though, but can't make it global.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ProvidePlugin just replaces globally the string provided with the instance of the module defined.

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        '$': 'jquery',
        '$.each': 'moment'
    })
```

The above plugin now replaces all instances of `$` in your code with the instance of jquery.
And in the second case, it replaces `$.moment` with the instance of moment.

You have to understand that ProvidePlugin simply renames the module to the string you provide and I guess that is kind of an override.

Comment: i tried something like `'THREE': './myCustomTHREE.js'` but that didn't work. I'm not clear what 'jquery' or 'moment' refer to here, is it the path in /node_modules, or something else?

Alternatively, i tried the expose-loader but that didn't work either, i only got the library where i made the `require(expose?...)`

Comment: is this the equivalent of making every `'$'` into `'require('jquery')?`

Comment: Exactly! It will treat `THREE.Something` as a placeholder for any module you would want to include there.

Comment: i was a bit confused with how the path was resolved, after i've done absolute (but relative to the entry point), basically `'THREE': '/myCustomThree.js'` it worked! Replacing the constructor seems a bit messy but i think i got it to do what i wanted :)