# $ is not defined when use webpack.ProvidePlugin

Tags: jquery, angularjs, webpack

I'm trying to use jquery with webpack but even though I use Webpack Provider plugin like:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    'window.$': 'jquery',
    $: 'jquery'
})
```

Seems like does not expose my jQuery to window global scope.

Comment: Maybe could be solved by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38278862/overriding-a-method-on-a-global-module-in-webpack/38295490#38295490)

Comment: What's your test?

Answer (score 4):

As I understand it, the [ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/) provides those variables to other WebPacked code but not external code or inline scripts.

The ['expose-loader'](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/expose-loader/) plugin alternately exposes global variables outside of the webpacked bundles. Add the following to your rules to define global jQuery and $ variables that point to your bundled jQuery.

```
rules:[
...
// Expose jquery globally for inline/legacy use
{
    test: require.resolve('jquery'),
    use: [
        { loader: 'expose-loader', options: 'jQuery' },
        { loader: 'expose-loader', options: '$' }
    ]
},
...
]
```

Comment: Adding both of these things doesn't solve this for me.

Comment: Is Jquery included in your vendor bundle? I'm using Webpack 3.10.0 and have jquery in a app-vendor.js entry point, then expose it as a global (you can check for this in the browser debugger) using that plugin. Alternately you can declare it an external, include a direct link to Jquery on a CDN and then use the provide plugin to make sure all your webpacked code sees it without a special import. To be honest though, webpack is still a giant fuzzy mystery to me.

Comment: Yeah it's in my vendor bundle, placed there via the CommonsChunkPlugin. Using webpack 2.x at the moment. Right now I get the same result (no Jquery defined for anything that needs it on any page) if I use either the loader with require.resolve, the ProvidePlug in, use both, or use neither. Seems to me that no approach actually results in anything being invoked.

Comment: After looking more deeply after reading your comment, it's interesting that $ and window.jQuery etc are defined if I check in the console (after the torrent of errors). I must have some problem with some dependencies not properly wired up to webpack.

Comment: Could be, if the code throwing the error is in your webpack bundles, the ProvidePlugin should fill in any gaps, mine was outside in old legacy code inline in the page so the "expose" bit was necessary.

Comment: Worked for me. You're a lifesaver <3

Comment: In Webpack 4, the options value needs to be different: `options: { exposes: ['$', 'jQuery'] }` See https://webpack.js.org/loaders/expose-loader/#using-configuration